# Windows Setup (and boot) stuck at classpnp.sys

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I had a Lenovo IdeaPad Y450A-PEI laptop with an Arch Linux installed on harddisk. I used to have a Windows 7 and a Fedora on it and they're fine.

Now I'm trying to install Windows 8 but when it goes into boot screen (with a super ugly fish) it stucks there. Those dots at the bottom of the screen move a bit and stop for a long time, then move a bit again. After approximately 30 minutes I'm able to get into Setup screen. Setup is fine, but after reboot it stucks just like before.

I also try Windows 7. Same, it stucks at the glowing Windows logo (should be an animated one), after a long time there's Setup, and reboot, another long time, Setup continues, another reboot, then stuck. I have no patience to wait for more than 15mins. Going into Safe Mode only tells me that it stucks at CLASSPNP.SYS.

Changing BIOS option AHCI to IDE: no luck, but when loading CLASSPNP.SYS a BSoD flashed and reboot. Also no luck in Setup.

I've tried nearly all possible solutions but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your hard drive and then check if it works. If it does, then you have a problem with your hard drive.

You could also try to buy an external kit for your hard drive and then recover your data from it.

Comment: That Arch Linux works well, can I say that there's no problem with the harddisk and why? Many thanks for further explanation.